# Finding the cursor size in MongoDB

Tags: javascript, mongodb

```
collection.find({description : data.story.description}, function(err, cursor){
  cursor.each(function(err, item){
    if(item != null){
      console.log("duplicate found\n"+util.inspect(item));
    }
  })
})
```

Is it possible to get the size of the cursor, without using a counter in the each loop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are checking for duplicates, you may wish to try the count() method attached to collection.  E.g.:

```
collection.count({description: data.story.description}, function(err, count) {
  if (count > 1) console.log("Duplicates found!");
});
```

Cursor.toArray() is just using cursor.each() on the back end. My example assumes you are checking post-insert(), but you could check pre- with (count > 0) and call insert() if (count == 0).

Answer (score 1):

Found a reasonable solution:

```
collection.find({description : data.story.description}).toArray(function(err,items){
   console.log("Items:" + items.length);
})
```

Using toArray, and the .length property of the array to find its size!

Comment: This will try to load all items into memory, which might exhaust your available resources. If you just need the count, then use the approach in the other answer.